# How to escape / added in json key and value using java?

Tags: java, json

I want to remove \ both front and back, I tried replace all but no luck. Refer the json and code. Note When I print the payload after decoding and the json looks good. After adding in the map like map.put("userInfo", payload) and it's appended with /.

{

```
  "userInfo": "{\"exp\":1620997117,\"iat\":1620996817,\"jti\":\"93ba2e8a-0310-4288-b6b9-2222222..}}
```

// code

```
String[] chunks = accessToken.split("\\.");
        Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
        String payload = new String(decoder.decode(chunks[1]));
        
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("token", accessToken);
        map.put("pid", userExtension.getProfileId());
        map.put("userInfo", payload);
```

Comment: can u comment what is the expected output?

Comment: @mattyman "userInfo": "{"exp":1620997117,"iat":1620996817,"....}